# Can not find symbol error in java method

Tags: java

I'm having problems with the y variable at line 20 22 24 of the code it gives the error of can not find symbol y. can some one help? Below is the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class primenumbers
{
    public static void main( String args [] )
    {
        System.out.println(" Start of program ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        int x;
        System.out.println(" Please enter a number ");
        x = input.nextInt();
        seePrime( x );
        System.out.println(" End of program ");
    }

    public static void seePrime( int y );
    {
        for ( int i = 2; i < y ; i++ )
        {
            int b = y % i**;
            if ( b == 0 )
                System.out.println( " number is not prime " );
            else
                System.out.println( " number is prime " );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code sensibly next time...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As a common courtesy to people who volunteer their time and expertise, please format your code correctly. There's a little box to the right of the editor that explains how to do so.

Comment: Just BTW, you could have found the answer just by proofreading your code for syntax.

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem:

```
public static void seePrime( int y );
```

You shouldn't have the semi-colon there.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the semi-colon at

```
public static void seePrime( int y );
```

> A statement is terminated with a semicolon. A hanging semicolon like
>   this simply terminates the current statement.

Answer (score 3):

Why there is colon at end? Remove it.

```
public static void seePrime( int y )
```